# Seeing if there is a possible train route through Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

A problem I'm working on with Prolog is to see if a train can travel from one destination to the next. There are two rules.

1. A train can travel through on or more intermediary from one destination to the next.
   Ex: San Francisco to Los Angeles
       Los Angeles to Irvine
       Irvine to San Diego
   This gives a route from San Francisco to San Diego.
2. A train can travel to and from a destination. So if a train can travel from San Francisco to Los Angeles, it can travel from Los Angeles to San Francisco.

This is the code I currently have.

```
nonStopTrain(sandiego,oceanside).
nonStopTrain(lasvegas,sandiego).
nonStopTrain(sanfrancisco,bakersfield).
nonStopTrain(bakersfield,sandiego).
nonStopTrain(oceanside,losangeles).
nonStopTrain(portland,sanfrancisco).
nonStopTrain(seattle,portland).

canTravel(From, To) :- nonStopTrain(From, To); nonStopTrain(To, From).
canTravel(From, To) :-
    canTravel(From, Through), canTravel(Through, To).
```

The problem is the ability to travel bidirectionally. When I run this program, I keep running back and fourth between the same places, and I'm not exactly sure why.

Comment: The problem is Prolog's depth-first search. The first 15 answers you get are legitimate, the problem is you then loop going back-and-forth between two locations (oceanside and losangeles, in my testing). The solution is to make the possibilities explicit and switch to a breadth-first search, but I don't have time right now to code it.

Comment: Your answer seems to make sense, but I'm not sure how to make it breadth-first search and to make the possibilities explicit. Could you please get back to me?

Comment: I will later tonight when I have some time, but there are other people who may get you a good answer first. In the mean time, you could try searching for breadth-first search and see if anything helps.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with a naive solution is that there are an infinite number of ways to get from point A to point B if you don't eliminate cycles. Suppose I want to go from Seattle to San Francisco. Without handling cycles, we're going to get each of these as a unique solution:

```
seattle ->  portland -> seattle -> portland -> sanfrancisco
seattle ->  portland -> seattle -> portland -> seattle -> portland -> sanfrancisco
seattle -> (portland -> seattle) x N -> sanfrancisco
```

There's no limit to the number of times you can double back on yourself, so there's effectively an infinite number of solutions once you have as little as three nodes connected. In practice you don't want any solutions where you double back on yourself, but Prolog doesn't know that and there's no intuitive and naive way to prevent it.

One of the better ways forward is to simply keep track of where you've been. To do that we're going to need to make the predicate take an extra argument. First I've also introduced a helper predicate.

```
connectedDirectly(From, To) :- nonStopTrain(From, To) ; nonStopTrain(To, From).
```

Having this separated out will reduce the desire to call `canTravel` recursively when we really just want to attach one more leg to the journey. Now for `canTravel`:

```
canTravel(From, To)    :- canTravel(From, To, []).
```

This is an arity 2 rule that maps onto our new arity 3 rule. The list of places we've been is always empty initially. Now we need a base case:

```
canTravel(From, To, _) :- connectedDirectly(From, To).
```

This should be obvious. Now the inductive case is a little different, because we need to do two things: find a new leg to attach to the journey, make sure we haven't been through that leg before, and then recur, adding the new leg to the list of places we've been. Finally, we want to ensure we don't get large cycles where we end up where we started, so we add a rule to the end to make sure we don't.

```
canTravel(From, To, Visited) :-
  connectedDirectly(From, Through),
  \+ memberchk(Through, Visited),
  canTravel(Through, To, [Through|Visited]),
  From \= To.
```

Now if you run it you'll find you get 98 solutions and all the solutions are symmetric:

```
?- forall(canTravel(X, Y), (write(X-Y), nl)).
sandiego-oceanside
lasvegas-sandiego
sanfrancisco-bakersfield
... etc.
```

So, happily, we were able to avoid going for a breadth-first search solution.

**Edit**

I have apparently confused the situation by overloading the name `canTravel` for two separate predicates. In Prolog, a predicate is uniquely defined by the name *and* the arity, much like overloading in C++ or Java where the "effective method" is determined by the number of arguments and the name, not just the name.

Your intuition is correct—the empty list in `canTravel(From, To) :- canTravel(From, To, [])` is establishing an initial binding for the list of visited places. It's not exactly allocating storage so much as establishing a base case.

There are really two uses of canTravel inside itself. One of them is calling `canTravel/3` from `canTravel/2`. In this case, `canTravel/3` is really sort of like a helper, doing the actual work of `canTravel/2`, but with an internal variable that we are initializing to the empty list. The other use is `canTravel/3` from within `canTravel/3`, and for that we're both using it to achieve the same goal: recursion, Prolog's primary "looping" construction.

The third argument in `canTravel(From, To, _) :- connectedDirectly(From, To)` is what makes this clause part of `canTravel/3`. This is the base case of the recursion, so it doesn't need to consider the places we've visited so far (although the inductive case will prevent a circular journey). We could also check it here, but it turns out to be more expensive and have no effect on the resultset:

```
canTravel(From, To, Visited) :- connectedDirectly(From, To), \+ memberchk(To, Visited).
```

I concluded that if it was adding expense and complexity without changing the answers we could omit the check, which reduces the base case to the original one with the anonymous third variable.

It may make more sense to see this without the overloading, in which case it looks like this:

```
canTravel(From, To) :- canTravel_loop(From, To, []).

canTravel_loop(From, To, _) :- connectedDirectly(From, To).
canTravel_loop(From, To, Visited) :-
  connectedDirectly(From, Through),
  \+ memberchk(Through, Visited),
  canTravel_loop(Through, To, [Through|Visited]),
  From \= To.
```

**Edit 2**

Regarding the "bar operator," your intuition is once again correct. :) I'm using it here to prepend an item to a list. What's confusing you is that in Prolog, with unification, most expressions express *relationships* rather than *procedures*. So depending on the context, `[X|Xs]` might be used to construct a new list (if you have X and XS in hand) or it might be used to break an implicit list into a head `X` and tail `Xs`. Look at all the ways I can use it just from the repl:

```
?- X = hello, Xs = [world, new, user], Y = [X|Xs].
Y = [hello, world, new, user].
```

This is basically how we're using it in `canTravel`: we have Through and we have Visited, so we're making a new list with Through first and Visited as the tail, and that's the third parameter to the recursive invocation. In procedural terms, we're just adding Through to a variable we're using in our loop.

But because this is Prolog, we're not limited to using things in one direction:

```
?- Y = [hello, world, new, user], Y = [X|Xs].
X = hello,
Xs = [world, new, user].

?- Y = [hello, world, new, user], [X|Xs] = Y.
X = hello,
Xs = [world, new, user].
```

Notice that Prolog didn't care which direction the assignment happened in, but it managed to "work backwards" to figure out what X and Xs should be using Y. This is one of the magical things about Prolog. (Note that in the examples in this session I'm omitting the variables which are echoed back because they obscure the point.)

In general, you want predicates that can solve for different parameters. For instance, `member/2` can be used to test membership or to enumerate items. `append/3` can build a new list from two old lists, or it can enumerate all the ways to split a list into two segments, or it can find a prefix or suffix given a list and a suffix or prefix.

As you get more used to this functionality you'll stop thinking of Prolog rules as being like functions in other languages and start to see them as *relations*: logical "truths" that exist between certain constructions. `member/2` isn't written by trying to enumerate items or by seeking through a list looking for a particular value. It's implemented by saying: the relation `member(Item, List)` is *true* when the Item is the first thing in List:

```
member(Item, [Item|_]).
```

or else when Item is in the remainder of the list:

```
member(Item, [_|Tail]) :- member(Item, Tail).
```

This definition is sufficient for all the possible uses. If `Item` is not instantiated, it will be instantiated to the first item in the list, then the first item in the tail of that list, and so on. If `Item` is instantiated, it will be true if Item is the first item in the list or if it is the first item in the tail. Surprisingly, `member/2` can even be used to generate lists that contain a value:

```
?- member(1, X).
X = [1|_G274] ;
X = [_G8, 1|_G12] ;
X = [_G8, _G11, 1|_G15] .
```

You can see what happened there: the `_` in the second clause is being made into anonymous variables, so it's generating lists with the 1 in the first position, then the second, then the third, etc.

A lot of Prolog works like this. This one is also pretty surprising:

```
?- length(X, 3).
X = [_G273, _G276, _G279].
```

Hope this helps clarify things a bit more! :)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer really helped. However, I am confused about a couple of things because I'm still new to Prolog. What does the empty list in canTravel(From, To) :- canTravel(From, To, []). do? Does it create a new list to store visited areas in? And why do you use canTravel inside of canTravel? Also, for canTravel(From, To, _) :- connectedDirectly(From, To), why is there a third argument? I apologize for the questions, but I'm still getting used to Prolog.

Comment: I have edited the answer to discuss your questions, please take a look at it and let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Your explanation is actually very clear. Though, I just have one final question. When you use canTravel_loop(Through, To, [Through|Visited]), what is [Through|Visited] doing? Usually the bar splits the list right? From the looks of it, you're actually adding Through to the list Visit. Could you please explain to me the bar operator? I always get confused because I think it is splitting a list when it's actually adding to a list, but I don't see how it adds to a list when the operator is defined to split a list. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I've added a bit more exposition. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have use some specific Prolog system?

Your program will work as intended without modifications (well, you have to add `:- auto_table.` as a first line of your program) in a system with tabling support, like B-Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a cut will stop your infinite recursion issue because once it finds an answer it won't keep backtracking forever:

```
canTravel(From, To) :- nonStopTrain(From, To); nonStopTrain(To, From).
canTravel(From, To) :-
    canTravel(From, Through), canTravel(Through, To), !.
```

I have no doubt that there is a more correct solution than this though.

Comment: This gets you exactly one solution with an intermediate path. Basically, you got rid of the infinite recursion by getting rid of all the recursion.

Comment: This answer does not seem to work, because if I try to run canTravel(oceanside, seattle), the code loops through from oceanside to seattle and then los angeles to oceanside. I think I have a better sense of why my code doesn't work now though.